# How to target multiple strings with single regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have multiple strings such as

```
POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1
DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1
DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0
PATCH /interactive/architect/innovative/24%2f7 HTTP/1.1
```

I want to target all these strings with `regex`.

I tried the following pattern

```
pattern = r"([A-Z]* /([A-Za-z0-9])\D+ [A-Z]*/\d\.\d)"
```

Here is the full code

```
string = """
POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1
DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1
DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0
PATCH /interactive/architect/innovative/24%2f7 HTTP/1.1
"""

pattern = r"(?P<url>[A-Z]* /([A-Za-z0-9])\D+ [A-Z]*/\d\.\d)"

result = [item.groupdict() for item in re.finditer(pattern,string)]

result
```

This outputs the following

```
[{'url': 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1'},
 {'url': 'DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1'},
 {'url': 'DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0'}]
```

With this pattern, I am able to target the first three strings. But for the life of me, I am not able to figure out how to target the last string. This is just a sample of many more strings in the list. I need to make this dynamic so that the program is able to capture strings that are similar to this.

I am a rookie in python and have just started learning `regex`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `re.findall` here with the following regex pattern:

```
\b(?:POST|GET|PUT|PATCH|DELETE)\b /[^/\s]+(?:/[^/\s]+)* HTTP/\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

Script:

```py
string = """
POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1
DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1
DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0
PATCH /interactive/architect/innovative/24%2f7 HTTP/1.1
"""
matches = re.findall(r'\b(?:POST|GET|PUT|PATCH|DELETE)\b /[^/\s]+(?:/[^/\s]+)* HTTP/\d+(?:\.\d+)?', string)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1',
 'DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1',
 'DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0',
 'PATCH /interactive/architect/innovative/24%2f7 HTTP/1.1']
```

The regex pattern works by matching one of several HTTP methods in an alternation, to which you may add more methods if necessary.  Then, it matches a path, followed by `HTTP` and a version number.

Answer (score 1):

This regex works with the pattern: `([A-Z]* (?:/[A-z0-9+%]*)+ [A-Z]*/\d\.\d)`:

```
>>> string = """
POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1
DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1
DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0
PATCH /interactive/architect/innovative/24%2f7 HTTP/1.1
"""
>>> re.findall("([A-Z]* (?:/[A-z0-9+%]*)+ [A-Z]*/\d\.\d)", string)
['POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1',
 'DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1',
 'DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0',
 'PATCH /interactive/architect/innovative/24%2f7 HTTP/1.1']
```